# normal loop took less time than parallel loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, parallel-processing

let us consider following code

```
tic;
y=zeros(1000,1);
for n=1:1000
    z=randn(n);
    y(n)=max(svd(z));
end
plot(y);
toc
```

this  program in my computer   with the following  information
[image]

informs that

```
SVD_without_parallel
Elapsed time is 84.722488 seconds.
```

now i have decide  to  run this program in parallel,  first of all, i have created maximum number of workers in my computer

```
N = maxNumCompThreads
Warning: maxNumCompThreads will be removed in a future release. Please remove any instances of this
function from your code. 
> In maxNumCompThreads (line 26) 

N =

     4

parpool('local',4)
```

and run following code

```
tic;
y=zeros(1000,1);
parfor n=1:1000
    z=randn(n);
    y(n)=max(svd(z));
end
plot(y);
toc
```

which informs me that

```
SVD_with_parallel
Elapsed time is 94.041680 seconds.
```

can you advice me please what is reason of this ? does it means  that parallel programming in matlab is not effective when we have just one loop? how can i optimize given code?

Comment: Parallel is not always better than non-parallel. Parallel computing suffers highly of memory reads, it makes it very very slow. in your case, you give the whole matrix to each processor, so the speed you gain from using 4 processor may be lost because of 4 times more memory reads. Memory reads are way slower than math operations

Comment: Without knowledge of specific details, I'd like to throw in that it is perfectly possible that some code just benefits poorly from parallelization, especially if there is some coordination involved which may be more costly than the gain by parallelization. Furthermore, parallel memory accesses might cause cache misses which can cause relatively large delays.

Comment: and what will be  good strategy?

Comment: Hard to tell - so far, you have just found out that parallelization does not yield an advantage, which in a certain sense means that your initial implementation is not _too bad_.

Comment: also is there  any good book about load balancing ?

Comment: Do you use `z=randn(n)` on purpose or do you meant `z=randn(500)` or some other constant value? Depending on how parfor assigns the iterations to the threads, the load may not be balanced at all.

Comment: please check this http://www.icl.utk.edu/~luszczek/pubs/parallelmatlab.pdf

Comment: your main costly function `svd` performs computations in paralel. If it's inside a simple loop it can use the 4 cores at each iteration. It you use a parfor and run 4 iterations in paralel, each `svd` will no longer have 4 processors available but instead use one. So what you gain with parfor you loose in `svd`. The increase in time might be due to memory reads as Ander suggests.

Comment: Also as Emilien suggested, are you sure yo want to do `randn(n)`?? This will increase the matrix size with each iteration. You probable want to use a constant value for each iteration.